# assembling PCB, Cx is shown within IC outline - does this mean Cx goes on other side?

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly

Embarrassing question. I am assembling a PCB. Please see attached picture. C9 is within the boundry of IC3. Does this mean that C9 is installed on the other side of the board?

C9 = 100n X7R

[image]

Comment: It's the only way AFAIK.  You should probably use a socket for the IC.

Comment: Putting it on the reverse would probably be a good idea if that seems general suitable for the intended mounting of the board, though if you use a socket there are likely capacitors that could fit underneath.

Comment: That is bad placement. Seems you have no choice but to install it on the bottom. Then trim the leads before installing IC3.

Comment: whoever designed the PCB has made some errors.  .... just try to find R1 and R4 after the components are installed (and IC3 and IC12) .... that designer needs a swift kick in the britches

Comment: there's more bad things on that PCB layout than just placement of C9. I hope nothing on that board really is high frequency. The two ground-plane-alike structures definitely look more like the lovechild of a PIFA and a groundplane rather than a reasonable fill.

Comment: @jsotola notice how the lowest trace runs closer to the screw hole's keepout than to its neighbor? notice the funky routing of that trace to the IC contact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IC3 was probably intended to go in an ic socket:[image]